# Greek letters passed by argparse to matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, argparse

I am using `matplotlib` to plot some data, however labels for plots are send via `argparse`. The problem is - I want some of the labels to contain greek letters. Which "greek letter code" type should I use to handle it?

Comment: it should be fine. what problems are you encountering? where is a minimal working example that produces those problems?

Comment: `argparse` just uses the strings passed to the script via `sys.argv`.  That in turn get's its values from the shell.  Focus on the shell and `sys.argv`.  This isn't an `argparse` issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `argparse` to read in command line arguments for my legends for `matplotlib`. It translates Greek characters just fine when I specify something like `'$\Delta G$'` as an input argument (output as `ΔG`).